# How to use a renamed table in Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table tbl_Employee in my database which i want to show in view using Entity Framework.

Employee controller class

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
               List<Employee> empList = emp.Employees.ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

It is throwing error saying EmployeeContext does not contain any definition for "Employees" but i have created a DbSet property in the Emlpoyee Context class

here is the code

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<tbl_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think it might have something to do with the `[Table]` attribute in the Employee model class:

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the error i am getting while compiling

Error   1   'MVCDemo.EmployeeContext' does not contain a definition for 'employees' and no extension method 'employees' accepting a first argument of type 'MVCDemo.EmployeeContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

Comment: A hint to prevent future problems: don't return entity models to your views, introduce view models.

Comment: Please include all relevant compiler errors and warnings. You can copy them by right-clicking. Note that C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: @CodeCaster                                                     Error 1 'MVCDemo.EmployeeContext' does not contain a definition for 'employees' and no extension method 'employees' accepting a first argument of type 'MVCDemo.EmployeeContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I said: note that C# is case-sensitive. Your error shows lowercase "employees", the code shows `Employees`, capital `E`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Initially i was using Employees , if you look in my code i have used "Employees" only.It was not even showing in the intellisense neither "employees" nor "Employees" .So finally after trying every thing what guys suggested here i finally deleted my project and created again from the scratch and it is working fine now. So thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You must place: DbSet.

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In this example your entity is Employees, so you must declare the DbSet  as `DbSet<Employees>`

Comment: I tried it is not working, Actually i was using 'public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }' initially i changed it to tbl_Employee just to check if it works and i posted the edited code

Comment: It throws an exception? Or having a problem when compiling? Can you tell us/me which error throws?

Comment: Copy this:
public DbSet<Employee> employees { get; set; }
And be careful of adding the using too

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the strongly typed class name:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

`Table` will specify the name of the table in your database. [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn)

You can also use fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("tbl_Employee");
}
```

Comment: where i need to put this code ? In the context class?

Comment: Inside `OnModelCreating` in `EmployeeContext`.